# use operators in templates in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a List class using pointers and am trying to implement a function LOCATE(T x) where T is for the template and returns the first position of the element x if found, else returns last position + 1.

My functions code is

```
template<class T>
    int List<T>::locate(T n) const
    {
        int size = end();
        Node<T> * p = head_;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (p->data() == n) // fails on this line
                return i;
            p = p->link();
        }
        return size; // if no match found
     }
```

I initialise my list with T as string as

```
List<string> myList;
```

but I get an error message

'bool std::operator ==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::string

Why is the error coming up even though the '==' operator is defined for the string class?
'

The code for Node is

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
  public:

    // Constructors
    Node();
    Node(T d, Node<T> * l = NULL);

    //Inspectors 
    T data() const;
    Node<T> * link() const;

    // Mutators 
    void data(T d); // assigns new value to Node
    void link(Node<T> * l); // points this Node to a different one

    // Destructor
    ~Node();

    private:
  Node<T> * link_;
  T data_;
};

template<typename T>
    T Node<T>::data() const
    {
        return data_;
    }
template<typename T>
    Node<T>* Node<T>::link() const
    {
        return link_;
    }
```

The calling code is

```
List<string> test;
test.add("abc");
cout << test.locate("abc") << endl;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for Node?

Comment: What does your definition of Node<T> look like? And the full calling code, the one that begins with "List<string> myList;", as above?

Thanks.

Comment: Just posted the definitio of Node<T> and the calling code

Comment: you should just post everything. this code seems fine.

Comment: If i remove the line that has '==' operator in it, rest of the code work perfectly.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008.

Comment: Not related to the question so its a comment: In general try passing objects by const ref. ie. in the locate function pass in a 'const T& n'. Won't notice a difference with built in types, but if you use your list for large objects you're throwing away your CPU with copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
if( n.compare(p->data()) == 0 )
```

[string::compare documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

As the comments below have noted, operator== should work. Please double check that you have

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

Comment: That's all well and good... but you really didn't solve the problem. operator== should work.

Comment: @rlbond most definitely. I know some documentation for string (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) does not include operator==, but visual c++ does (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ww0haah.aspx)

Comment: It's in the standard, section 21.2.

Comment: wow. I missed the include<string> in the main file. I guess its too late in the night (2 AM here) to continue writin code. The == works after the include statement.

Answer (score 4):

Without getting neck-deep in your code, I notice several problems.

Firstly,

```
locate(T n)
```

should be

```
locate(const T& n)
```

This saves a possible copy of n

And to ask a stupid question, are you sure you've done:

```
 #include <string>
```

Comment: Good call on asking about the include

Comment: Well done..according to latest comment by OP, the include file turns out to be the problem.

Comment: "I notice several problems." You only spotted one problem.

Comment: I pointed out two. The "locate" method, and the possibility of a missing include file.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `std::istreambuf_iterator` is peculiar as nothing in the code you show justifies it -- can you please show us `Node` and whatever other code impinges on this in a minimal failing example? Trying to evince the problem from very partial code and an error message is very much like pulling teeth...!-)

Answer (score 0):

This looks OK, I can't see how the `std::istreambuf_iterator` gets into the picture...

One thing you may want to adjust is taking `const T&` instead of `T` as in-parameters to your methods, e.g.

```
  Node(const T& d, Node<T> * l = NULL);
  void data(const T& d);

  int List<T>::locate(const T& n) const { ...
```

What with the actual problem, there's bound to be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Start deleting code untill it works again. Some typo or rogue macros or conflicting namespaces screw things up.

Will this compile by itself?

```
string data = "bla";
Node<string> p("bla");
bool b = p.data() == data;
```

(Every C++ programmer should make a cout << "bla" << end; typo. Very entertaining)